# Can I find the Oracle schema user name and password knowing just the SID?

Tags: oracle

I have an application running on a Linux machine. The application is using Oracle as back end.

I do not know the user name and password or any schema which the oracle is using to run the application. All I know is the Oracle SID. Can I know the oracle user name and password with this that is required to run the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without a lot more information, no.

Imagine that you could get a username and a password only by knowing the SID and, presumably, the IP address of the server the database is running on.  That would meam that it would be incredibly trivial to break in to any database in the world.  A SID is a [12 character string that is case-insensitive on some platforms and is limited to letters and numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create003.htm#ADMIN11074).  That would be a rather insensitive password.  But a SID is also needed to connect to the database so it has to be widely distributed.  If that was all that was necessary to break in to a database, no one would use Oracle for anything remotely important.

Comment: no config file nothing can be used to find the username and password?

Comment: @MeghaSharma - No reputable program would store a password in clear text in a config file.  No reasonable program would store a password in clear text anywhere.  Oracle, like other reasonably secure applications, only stores password hashes which are, by definition, not reversable short of breaking the hash.

Comment: Why do you need the username / password? Why is resetting it not acceptable?

Comment: I want to migrate the application running on one server to another. fr this I need to import the databse

Comment: @MeghaSharma - If you have superuser access to the server, you can do a full export and then a full import on the new server without ever needing to know the username or the password that the application is using to connect.

Comment: Ok, see my edits in my answer, added after your additional information. Start with the V$SESSION view.

Comment: I have taken the dump and I need to import the dump to the RDS oracle, service by AWS. But I am getting lots of error.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only thing you can possibly do, remotely, with the SID and address of the machine is to connect to the TNS listener and query the services (depending on listener configuration).

Otherwise, I'd be selling my Oracle license for security concerns. :)

If you are on the machine itself, unless you have a user account on the database, or belong to the dba or osoper group or the like, you will not be able to connect to the database. Not in interest of hacking, but for information purposes, if you have an OS account, the only thing you might see is sqlplus, sqlldr or export sessions with credentials in the command string (which is why on a non-private machine you should always login to those utilities in prompt mode and not by passing the credentials on the command line).

The OP updated the question:

Login to Oracle as sysdba from the OS account, and query the **v$session** view while the app is active. If the app is logging in, it will show up in v$session. If you have trouble that way, but you happen to know a table name, query SYS.DBA_TABLES for the table name, and note the OWNER column. Or look at V$SQLAREA or one of the other dynamic views that shows current or recent SQL queries on the system.

Example:

```
root# su - oracle
oracle@linuxdb ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> select username, status, program from v$session where username is not null;
```

You can view or export the schema, once you know which one, without the app password. Once you reset the password, you will not be able to recover it. I would, instead, set the SYSTEM password, then run expdp (or exp) and export the schema. Something like:

```
oracle@linuxdb ~]$ expdp system/manager schemas=appschema <other parameters here...>
```

Comment: I Have the access to the machine on which oracle is installed, do oracle have any config file ?? which stores the database user names and password

Comment: If you have physical access to the database server as a sufficiently privileged operating system user, you can use operating system authentication to log in to the database and reset any passwords you'd like.  You still wouldn't be able to determine the current password, though, unless you wanted to launch an attack to break the hash algorithm Oracle uses.

Comment: +1 to justin's comment. So now I see you may have access to the root or oracle account. If you have root, su - oracle, then use "sqlplus / as sysdba" and you can reset any DB password you like.

Comment: @Megha Sharma - It would help if you clarified your full situation.

Comment: yes that is feasible I know but I do not know what user name or schema the application uses. Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: I have the machine access on which oracle is installed. An application is using the oracle database. But I do not know what schema the app is using

Comment: After executing the query I m getting the answer as : `USERNAME                       STATUS
------------------------------ --------
PROGRAM
------------------------------------------------
SFREPLADM                      INACTIVE
JDBC Thin Client

SYS                            ACTIVE
sqlplus@WA1SANDSALESD02 (TNS V1-V3)

SFREPLADM                      INACTIVE
JDBC Thin Client`

Comment: So there is your answer "SFREPLADM". If you want to discuss more, I recommend asking a new question, you've closed this one, plus the original question no longer applies.

Comment: I have updated the output of your command in my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52643/discussion-between-megha-sharma-and-mrjoltcola)

Comment: I recommend you reverse the edit, because Justin and my answers no longer apply if you change the question. Create a new question.

Comment: I have posted a new question .